# F# compiler complaining of invalid type in recursive function

Tags: recursion, f#

In F# I am trying to write a function that given two strings it will return all indexes of the start of the second string in the first string.  My function looks like this:

```
let allIndexOf (str:string) (c:string) =
    let rec inner (s:string) l =
        match (s.IndexOf(c), (s.IndexOf(c)+1) = s.Length) with
        | (-1, _) -> l
        | (x, true) -> x::l
        | (x, false) -> inner(s.Substring(x+1) x::l)
    inner str []
```

The problem is on the line `(x, false) -> inner(s.Substring(x+1) x::l)` the compiler says expected type int list but got int list -> int list.  What am I doing wrong here?

In this case I want to call inner with the rest of the string (minus the part where it matched) to look for more matches.

Comment: I'm not certain it will gives the result you expect because recursive call with only a substring of the original string will "offset" the results. For example using `allIndexOf "foobar" "o"` will gives `[0; 1]` the 1 is the first index of "o" in "foobar" (note the reversed results BTW) and the 0 is the index of "o" in "obar" results of Substring

Comment: *can't edit previous comment so I'll add here* I made a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iy4p1Q) to illustrate (with various ways of doing it since I don't know if recursion is mandatory or not)

Comment: @Sehnsucht thanks for taking the time to point this out. Proves how awesome the SO community is.  Your Comprehension func is correct but I've just tried another test case: "foobarmanhelloman" "man" and it appears the RecursionWithAccumulator and RecursionWithContinuation for this case.  It should be [6, 14] but the second two give the answer [6]

Comment: Thanks @Sehnsucht with your help I've fixed the original function by passing in the offset so far and adding that on to the results https://dotnetfiddle.net/2JjfXr

Comment: oh just a little mistake I should have used > instead of >= for idx check (I've edited the code). As a side note now your code is correct but using substring create unnecessary overhead (creating new string where you only need to loop on them) but that's secondary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you forget the parens between the first and the second argument?

```
    | (x, false) -> inner (s.Substring(x+1)) (x::l)
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. I don't understand why you need parens around (s.Substring(x+1))?

Comment: Because it's a single argument, if you don't put parens there it might be interpreted as arg1 = s.Substring and arg2= x+1

Comment: Ok I see, I would've thought that by putting s.Substring(x+1) it's clear that it's a single argument as you are passing the result of s.Substring(x+1). I guess my brain still works in imperative mode :)

Comment: Yes, don't forget here you have currying. An expression like s.Substring well can be interpreted as a partial applied function.